# Android App has stopped working when getting html page with Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I am a newbie to Android App Development. My android app shows "Unfortunately, AppTest has stopped." when I try to connect to Internet with **Jsoup** with the following code.

I have already added Internet permission to **AndroidManifest.xml**.
Jsoup is working correctly when I test with just offline html such as `<p>Nay</p>`.
My Android phone is completely available Internet Connection. What is wrong?

```
    Document doc;
    try {
        // need http protocol
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").get();

        // get page title
        String title = doc.title();
        psi.setText(title);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: post the stack trace and some more code

Comment: I have debugged this app. The errors seem to occur on HttpConnection. In Class File Editor, it showed "Source not found", "The JAR of this class file belongs to container 'Android Private Libraries' which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries.

Comment: The crash doesn't come from this code, the exception is properly handled. We need more code to help you.

Comment: stack trace or didn't happen

Comment: Yeah, the error message you quoted isn't very useful or relevant; all it means is that you don't have the source code to Jsoup, so you can't see the code where the failure was or set breakpoints. You really need to show us the error messages and stack trace from the logcat output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all, but the answers and suggestions could not help me very much. After doing a lot of mistakes, I have found the solution. I would like to post my answer to help other people when meet this problem.

**Jsoup** seems to run in another thread than UI thread. Therefore, you just need to create another thread with **AsyncTask** to use **Jsoup** like the following.

```
class GetHtmlwithJsoup extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
protected String doInBackground(String... param) {  
   try {
     //Jsoup Connecting and Getting html page code at here
   } 
   catch (TwitterException e) {
     return "Failed to get";
   }
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) { // 
   super.onProgressUpdate(values);
   // Not used in my case
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) { // 
   //show Jsoup HTML Ouput to UI widgets code at here...  
}
}
```

Comment: It's not Jsoup fault, simply you cannot do Internet calls in a UI thread.

Comment: @ Enrichman, yes. It's my fault putting Internet calls in UI thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `doc` outside this block, you must check if it was properly initialized.

Other guess, does your app request the [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission?